# Could not load ssl library error when doing HTTPS post

Tags: ssl, https, delphi-2010

I am trying to do a HTTPS connection but keep on getting the "Could not load sll library" error.
I have spent the whole morning reading and surfing but I cannot find a solution to my problem.
I downloaded the latest OpenSSL v1.0.2u today, and also have the following configuration:
Indy version: 10.6.2.0
Delphi 2010
Windows 10 x64
According to the Readme.txt file, the installation instructions are "Copy both DLL files into your application directory" - which I have done.

My code to do the http post:

```
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Result: string;
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create();
  try
    IdHTTP.Request.Accept := 'application/json';
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentEncoding := 'utf-8';
    idHttp.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create();
    IdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
    IdHTTP.Request.Authentication := TIdBasicAuthentication.Create;
    Result := IdHTTP.Post('https://testapi.xxxx.com/esb/calendar/doSomething', Memo1.Lines);
    ShowMessage('HTTP Result: ' + Result);
    ShowMessage('HTTP ResponseText: ' + IdHTTP.ResponseText);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(IdHTTP);
  end;
```

Any suggestions what I can try?
Thanks!

Comment: After the error occurs, call Indy's `WhichFailedToLoad()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit to find out why it is failing. Either the DLLs themselves can't be loaded into memory, or they are missing exports that Indy requires. Is your app 32bit or 64bit? Are the DLLs you are using 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: Thanks for the input Remy. I was under the impression the DLLs had to match the operating system. I installed the 32bit version and voila, problem solved. Now I get the "Socker Error # 10060. Connection Timed Out." error. It happens instantaneous so I don't think it is a real time-out issue. If I run the same app on my other pc, I get an "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error" message. My server is up-and-running and I can send requests using Insomnia.

Comment: "*I was under the impression the DLLs had to match the operating system*" - no, they need to match your program. A 32bit EXE running on a 64bit system still needs 32bit DLLs. "*Now I get the "Socker Error # 10060. Connection Timed Out." error ... If I run the same app on my other pc, I get an "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error" message*" - those are separate issues different than the DLL issue, so they should be posted as new questions.

Comment: Thanks again for all the help Remy. It turns out there was something wrong with my Dev machine's o/s and it wasn't binding properly to the socket. After upgrading everything to the latest and greatest and running a repair on the Delphi installation, all my problems have been solved.